# Symfony3.4: Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Expected response code 220 but got an empty response

Tags: php, ssl, smtp, swiftmailer, symfony-3.4

Project in symfony 3.4 framework, all functions are ready, but an exception to get errors in the process is not working because swiftmailer is not working

<parameters.yml>
mailer_transport: smtp
mailer_host: <<--IP-->
mailer_user: email@exemple.com
mailer_password: NULL
mailer_port: 25

---

Name                      | Transport  | Spool  | Delivery  | Single Address

---

default (default mailer) |  smtp     |   YES  |   YES      |  email@exemple.com

---

ERROR     [app] Exception occurred while flushing email queue: Expected response code 220 but got an empty response.

Comment: When hooking up external resources to some code, the first step in testing that is proving that the external resource works _outside_ of the code. Are you sure there is an SMTP server listening on port 25 at that host that accepts naive traffic like this? Can you send a mail using telnet to prove that? Show what debugging steps you have taken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution:
I gave access to my IP in the whitelist.
Being port 25 SMTP, comment on the TLS encryption because it is not used.

Note that it was for local use at the development level.

I already altered for safe values in production, Thank you.